# MIME type & File signature of .DD image file?

Tags: dd

Please tell me the mime type & file signature of .DD image file which is a disk image created with DD command line tool in Linux/Unix.

Answer (score 0):

You mean the magic number? There is none, in the case of `dd` it's just raw bytes.